Multiple Problems with connecting Firebase to Flutter Project
I've been trying to connect Firebase to a Flutter project and am running into problems at every turn.

I downloaded the Firebase CLI for Windows and added it to the file where my Flutter project is
Via Firebase CLI, I checked that I was logged in (command: firebase login) and checked my Firebase project was there (firebase projects: list). I was logged in and the project was there.
I ran flutter doctor, and all came back with green ticks.
I then ran npm i -g firebase-tools and I'm getting errors everywhere:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\m.cache\firebase\tools\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Users\m.cache\firebase\runtime/shell.bat -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! '--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-09T23_12_28_964Z-debug-0.log

I also tried running npm install -g firebase-tools --force, which had the same output.

Any idea how I can fix this?
